# Using ping in a foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, csv, timer, automation, ping

I have an assignment in C# involving automation. My code is mainly based off things I have found online. My current problem is I am trying to read in IP addresses line by line from a CSV file into an array, pinging each object of the array, and appending the object so that each object will read "IP, status(if the ping was successful), response time"

I am trying to use a foreach loop but am running into errors. I am on a Mac so it is using mono. Any help would be appreciated.

(Full assignment below if it helps explain anything)

Starting with a premade C# console application, your application will upon running allow for three commands – start, stop, and exit. The application will, upon first running, ask the user for a CSV file (the user must provide a CSV file). This file will contain web addresses (1 per line) – the professor will supply the initial file.
Your application will be setup with a timer so that every time the timer runs, it pings the provided web addresses, gathering whether the server responds or not and the response time of each server. The timer should run continuously from the point the user types “start” until they type “stop” or “exit”. The data will be recorded back to another CSV file, containing the web address, response time, and whether or not the server responded at all.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace MT_proj4
{

public class Program
{
    public static String[] addressArray = File.ReadAllLines("Project04_URLs.csv");

    public static string IP;
    public bool status;
    public string time;


    public static void Main() 
    {
        foreach (string s in addressArray) 
        {
            IP = Console.ReadLine();
            bool PingHost(string)
            {
                bool pingable = false;
                    #pragma warning disable XS0001 // Find APIs marked as TODO in Mono
                Ping pinger = new Ping();
                    #pragma warning restore XS0001 // Find APIs marked as TODO in Mono
                try
                {
                    PingReply reply = pinger.Send(IP);
                    pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
                }
                catch (PingException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < addressArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    addressArray[i] = addressArray[i] + pingable;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    static void TimerClass()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
        timer.Elapsed += HandleTimer;
        timer.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'exit' to close...");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a command...");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Command: ");
            string command = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Command entered: " + command);

            if (command.ToLower() == "stop")
                timer.Stop();

            else if (command.ToLower() == "exit")
                break; 
        }
    }

    static void HandleTimer(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nHandler not implemented...");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I would restructure this a bit.  The ping code should run its own thread.  Remove the timer, and simply block on Console.ReadLine().  If the results are not expected, repeat until you get either stop or exit

Comment: bool PingHost(string) Error CS1001: Identifier expected (CS1001) + PingHost says not all code paths return a value

Comment: @tatmanblue i am not sure what you mean? where would the Console.ReadLine() go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would restructure your solution a bit. The ping code should run its own thread. Remove the timer, and simply block on Console.ReadLine(). If the results are not expected, repeat until you get either stop or exit.

The reason is the ping work and the console processing are on the same thread.  These will block.

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pinging....until stop command");
        Thread pinger = new Thread(DoPinging);
        pinger.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            string command = Console.ReadLine();

            if (command.ToLower() == "stop")
                break;

            else if (command.ToLower() == "exit")
                break;

            Console.WriteLine("Ignoring-> " + command);
        }

        pinger.Abort();
    }

    static void DoPinging() 
    { 
        // here goes the pinging code
    }
}
```

In your example code, it looks like you want to read input for ping from Console as well, after the line read, if the value doesn't equal the stop commands (stop, exit), put the value into a queue and let the ping code read from the queue.

You mention reading a CSV file for the addresses to ping (but your example code doesn't reference a file).  You can take this as a command line argument (string[] passed in main) and do the work for processing the file in the DoPinging method.

If you want me to add more detail to that, please comment below and I will work on that.

Thnx
Matt

Comment: okay so I just put my same ping code starting from IP = Console.ReadLine(); correct? It is still giving me the errors for identifier expected and PingLine says not all code paths return a value but everything else is making a lot more sense (THANKS FOR THAT)

Comment: (I fixed the identifier problem)

Comment: awesome :)  feel free to post your results in your question above so that others can learn from it